# Cant set state hook inside useImperativeHandle hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to call child function from parent and set state of a child's hook ,but I cant able to success it ,simple code is below ,setstate isnt working inside useImperativeHandle.Any help is appreciated ,thx..

```
  const child = forwardRef((props,ref) => {

 const [pagerTotalCount, setPagerTotalCount] = useState(0);
    const [customerData, setCustomerData] = useState([]);
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       childFunction1: updatePagerTotalCount; 
      }));

})
const updatePagerTotalCount = (param) => {
   setPagerTotalCount(param); // this IS working now...
   const pagerInputModel = {
            "pageNumber": 1,
                "pageSize": 3,
          };
          myservice.listCustomerList(pagerInputModel).then((res) => {
            const { isSuccess, data: customers} = res;
            if (isSuccess) {     
              console.log("api result:" + JSON.stringify(customers)); // this IS working,api IS working
                 setCustomerData(customers); // this IS NOT working , cant SET this.
              console.log("hook result:" + JSON.stringify(customerData));  //EMPTY result.I tested this WITH another buttonclick even IN ORDER TO wait FOR async,but still NOT working
            } 
          });
};


const parent= () => {
   
    const childRef = React.useRef(null)
       const handleClick = () => {
        childRef.current.childFunction1(11); //sending integer param to child 
      };
      RETURN(
        <> 
           <Button variant="contained" endIcon={<FilterAltIcon />} onClick={handleClick}>
                            Filtrele
                        </Button>
          <child  ref={childRef}/>
          </>
      )
         
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define a function to update the state and return that function via `useImperativeHandle`.

```
const updatePagerTotalCount = (param) => {
   setPagerTotalCount(param);
};

useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    childFunction1: updatePagerTotalCount; 
}));
```

Now with above when `childRef.current.childFunction1(11);` is invoked via parent component, you can see the state is being set correctly.

Comment: thx this is working ,but now I have another problem,I edited my code .I cant able to set an array from api call to a hook.It always show empty.

Comment: Thanks Slayer for confirmation. Can you please format the code so that it is easy to read.. You can also the query a new question instead of updating the current only. Also, would it be ok to share the codesandbox link so that it's easy for repro and to provide suggestions for the change.

Comment: State are updated async instead of sync. So having `console.log` after setState won't guarantee to log the write state. You can use the `useEffect` hook with dependency on `customers` state to log this console.log.

Comment: yes I know that,but when I set json array ,shouldn't the datagrid be loaded with that data after sometime? Or should I use useffect as you said?

Comment: I created a codesandbox sample ,its working.I guess my real code has something else.thx. https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-wright-61s3xm?file=/src/childcomp.js